# (RxJava) ported Groovy method doesn't work

Tags: java, android, groovy, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am porting my Android app written in Java to Groovy. I am trying to use Groovy closure but it doesn't work. No error when I compile and run but nothing happens.

This is the version that doesn't work.

```
    Observable.create({
        Subscriber<Bin> subscriber ->
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                void run() {
                    List<List<String>> lists = binData.getData()
                    for (List<String> strings : lists) {
                        try {
                            Bin bin = ... // shorten for brevity
                            subscriber.onNext(bin)
                        } catch (Exception ex) {}
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                }
            }).start()
    })
```

This version works fine. It's valid Groovy but kinda verbose.

```
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bin>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Bin> subscriber) {
            final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<List<String>> lists = binData.getData();
                    for (List<String> strings : lists) {
                        try {
                            Bin bin = ... // shorten for brevity
                            subscriber.onNext(bin)
                        } catch (Exception ex) {}
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                }
            })
            t.start()
        }
    })
```

I guess it's something to do with the closure or type but I can't figure out. Any idea? Thanks!

The example I followed is at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava#asynchronous-observable-example.

Comment: Did you try coercing the closure via `as Observable.OnSubscribe<Bin>`?

Comment: @BDKosher not yet. i'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @BDKosher you're right. thanks! do you want to answer? i'll accept it.

Comment: glad it worked! Posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to [Groovy 2.2](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.2+release+notes), closures had to be explicitly coerced in order to substitute for a specific type. And even after 2.2, there may be edge cases (e.g. [generic parameters](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6488)) where implicit coercion quite doesn't work as expected.

To coerce, apply the `as` operator. You can also replace the anonymous `Runnable` with a closure:

```
Observable.create({ Subscriber<Bin> subscriber ->
    new Thread({ ->
        List<List<String>> lists = binData.getData()
        ... // shorten for brevity
    } as Runnable).start()
} as Observable.OnSubscribe<Bin>)
```